Unmet Python Dependency Error While Installing Spot (w-Automata) on Ubuntu 24.04
I am trying to install Spot on an Ubuntu 24.04 virtual machine following the official instructions provided in the "Installing the Debian packages" section of the Spot website. The installation process seems to run smoothly for the first steps:

Adding the GPG key:

sudo wget -O /usr/share/keyrings/spot-archive-keyring.gpg https://www.lrde.epita.fr/repo/debian.gpg


Adding the Spot repository:

echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/spot-archive-keyring.gpg] http://www.lrde.epita.fr/repo/debian stable/' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spot.list


Updating the package list:

sudo apt-get update

However, the issue arises when running the final command to install Spot and its dependencies:
sudo apt-get install spot libspot-dev spot-doc python3-spot

I receive the following error:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-spot : Depends: python3 (< 3.12) but 3.12.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

This screenshot shows the exact Terminal Error : Error Terminal
From my understanding, Spot requires Python 3.11 or lower, but Ubuntu 24.04 comes with Python 3.12 by default. I attempted to resolve this by manually installing Python 3.10 and setting it as the default using update-alternatives, but the error persists.
I am unsure whether this issue is caused by my current configuration, an incompatibility with Ubuntu 24.04, or something I may have overlooked during the setup process.
Any insights into why this problem occurs would be greatly appreciated.
